# React antd 4 Form in Modal resetFields showing wrong data

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I am having trouble understanding why I am seeing this unexpected behavior.  If I have some data that I am passing into a prop on an object that has a modal with a form done as shown below and I click on a button, then cancel, then click on a different button, the form is showing the previously clicked state each time.  Within the useEffect code, I can see that the correct person is loaded, though the form initializes the previous person.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Button, Modal, Form, Input } from "antd";

const PersonEditForm = ({ person, onCreate, onCancel }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const prevRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevRef.current === null && person) {
      form.resetFields();
    }
    prevRef.current = person;
  });

  return (
    person && (
      <Modal
        visible={!!person}
        title="Person Editor"
        okText="Create"
        cancelText="Cancel"
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onOk={() => {
          form
            .validateFields()
            .then(values => {
              onCreate(values);
            })
            .catch(info => {
              console.log("Validate Failed:", info);
            });
        }}
      >
        <Form
          form={form}
          layout="vertical"
          name="form_in_modal"
          initialValues={person}
        >
          <Form.Item
            name="name"
            label="Name"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input the person's name!"
              }
            ]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    )
  );
};

const CollectionsPage = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(null);

  const onCreate = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
    setPerson(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          setPerson({ name: "Bob" });
        }}
      >
        Edit Bob
      </Button>
      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          setPerson({ name: "John" });
        }}
      >
        Edit John
      </Button>
      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          setPerson({ name: "Phil" });
        }}
      >
        Edit Phil
      </Button>
      <PersonEditForm
        person={person}
        onCreate={onCreate}
        onCancel={() => {
          setPerson(null);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<CollectionsPage />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

However, if I remove the `person && (` from my `<PersonEditForm>` component, it works as expected.  Can anyone explain the subtle difference I'm running into here?  I have down-stream complex form components that weren't handling a null state, so I wanted to only create the modal if a person was being edited.

Comment: Why are you using ref, you can add `person` as dependency in useEffect and call `form.resetField` without any condition

Comment: True enough, thanks!  Though, that has very little to do with my original question. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't work because of some funny race condition arising from misusing `form.resetForm` to change `initialValues`. You would probably have to go into the actual implementation of `initialValues` to figure out what is going wrong.

However, if instead of reseting the form inside of `useEffect`, you were to assign the clicked `person` value using `form.setFieldsValue(person)`, your code would work as intended.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-christian-cdn7t?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks, man!  I'm still getting used to this new v4 stuff.  It's awesome that they work with nested values on an object so well now and it never occurred to me to just reset the entire form object.